# Can't understand Ruby's magic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts

In railscasts project you can see this code:

```
before(:each) do
  login_as Factory(:user, :admin => true)
end
```

The corresponding definition for the function is:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:github_username) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
end
```

I can't understand how the admin parameter is passing to function, while in the function there's no word about admin parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Factory.define` is not a function definition, it is a method that takes a symbol or string (in this case user) and a block that defines the factory you are making.  `Factory(:user, :admin => true)` makes a `User` object, with admin attributes.  It is not calling the code in your second snippet, it is calling `Factory()` which initializes a factory, and selects one (in this case the one defined in second snippet). Then it passes options in hash form to Factory as well.

`Factory` selects the `:user` factory which is very generic.  The option `:admin=>true` just tells `Factory` to set the admin instance variable on User to true.

```
This is actually what it is calling in factory.rb in factory girl

def initialize(name, options = {}) #:nodoc:
  assert_valid_options(options)
  @name = factory_name_for(name)
  @options = options
  @attributes = []
end
```

So Factory(name,options) is equivalent to Factory.new(name,options) in this code.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html  Notice Array and String etc have similar constructs.  I am trying to figure out how they did that now.

This is all confusing even for decent Ruby programmers.  I recommend strongly the book "Metaprogramming Ruby" It is probably the best book I have read in ruby and it tells you a lot about this magic stuff.

Comment: I second the Metaprogramming Ruby book. I am new to Ruby and this book has given me a much deeper understanding of Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Michael Papile's response is essentially correct.  However, I'd like to elaborate upon it a bit as there are some technical nuances that you might wish to be aware of.  I looked over the code for **railscasts** and **factory_girl** and I believe there are a few extra pieces to the puzzle that explain how the **:admin => true** arg ends up creating the **admin** attribute of the user factory.  The attribute addition does not actually happen by way of **Factory**'s initialize() method, although as Michael pointed out that method is indeed being called in service of building the new user factory object.

I'm going to include in this explanation all the steps I took in case you'd like to see how to go about investigating similar questions you might have.

Since your original post is dated Feb. 17th I looked at the version of **railscasts** that closely matches that date.

I looked in its Gemfile:

https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/d124319f4ca2a2367c1fa705f5c8229cce70921d/Gemfile

Line 18:

```
gem "factory_girl_rails"
```

I then checked out the commit of **factory_girl_rails** that most closely matched the Feb 17th date.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/544868740c3e26d8a5e8337940f9de4990b1cd0b/factory_girl_rails.gemspec

Line 16:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency('factory_girl', '~> 2.0.0.beta')
```

**factory_girl** version 2.0.0.beta was actually not so easy to find.  There are no github tags with that name so I just checked out the closest in terms of commit date.

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb

Lines 122-128:

```
# Shortcut for Factory.default_strategy.
#
# Example:
#   Factory(:user, :name => 'Joe')
def Factory(name, attrs = {})
  Factory.default_strategy(name, attrs)
end
```

So the **Factory** invocation in railscasts is actually calling a convenience method which invokes the "default strategy", which is located in the same file:

Lines 39-52:

```
# Executes the default strategy for the given factory. This is usually create,
# but it can be overridden for each factory.
#
# Arguments:
# * name: +Symbol+ or +String+
#   The name of the factory that should be used.
# * overrides: +Hash+
#   Attributes to overwrite for this instance.
#
# Returns: +Object+
# The result of the default strategy.
def self.default_strategy(name, overrides = {})
  self.send(FactoryGirl.find(name).default_strategy, name, overrides)
end
```

Note that **FactoryGirl.find** is invoked to get the object on which to invoke **default_strategy**.  The **find** method resolves to here:

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb

Lines 12-14:

```
def find(name)
  @items[name.to_sym] or raise ArgumentError.new("Not registered: #{name.to_s}")
end
```

Here the name is **:user**.  Thus we wish to invoke **default_strategy** on the **user** factory.  As Michael Papile pointed out, this user factory was defined and registered by the railscasts code that you originally thought was the class definition for Factory.

https://ryanb/railscasts/blob/d124319f4ca2a2367c1fa705f5c8229cce70921d/spec/factories.rb

Lines 23-25:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.sequence(:github_username) { |n| "foo#{n}" }
end
```

So in investigating what the default strategy is for the user factory, I looked around in the railscasts project and found this:

https://ryanb/railscasts/blob/d124319f4ca2a2367c1fa705f5c8229cce70921d/spec/factories.rb

Lines 43-45:

```
def default_strategy #:nodoc:
  @options[:default_strategy] || :create
end
```

**:create** is the default strategy.  We go back to **factory_girl** to find the def for **create**.

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/syntax/methods.rb

Lines 37-55:

```
# Generates, saves, and returns an instance from this factory. Attributes can
# be individually overridden by passing in a Hash of attribute => value
# pairs.
#
# Instances are saved using the +save!+ method, so ActiveRecord models will
# raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exceptions for invalid attribute sets.
#
# Arguments:
# * name: +Symbol+ or +String+
#   The name of the factory that should be used.
# * overrides: +Hash+
#   Attributes to overwrite for this instance.
#
# Returns: +Object+
# A saved instance of the class this factory generates, with generated
# attributes assigned.
def create(name, overrides = {})
  FactoryGirl.find(name).run(Proxy::Create, overrides)
end
```

The create strategy calls the **run** method defined here:

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb

Lines 86-97:

```
def run(proxy_class, overrides) #:nodoc:
  proxy = proxy_class.new(build_class)
  overrides = symbolize_keys(overrides)
  overrides.each {|attr, val| proxy.set(attr, val) }
  passed_keys = overrides.keys.collect {|k| FactoryGirl.aliases_for(k) }.flatten
  @attributes.each do |attribute|
    unless passed_keys.include?(attribute.name)
      attribute.add_to(proxy)
    end
  end
  proxy.result(@to_create_block)
end
```

A translation/summarization of what this code is doing:

First, the **proxy** object is built by calling **new** on the **proxy_class**, which in this case is **Proxy::Create**, which is defined here:

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/proxy/create.rb

Basically all you need to know is that **proxy** is building a new user factory object and invoking callbacks before and after the factory object is created.

Going back to the **run** method, we see that all the extra args that were originally passed into the **Factory** convenience method (in this case, **:admin => true**) are now being labelled as **overrides**.  The **proxy** object then invokes a **set** method, passing in each attribute-name/value pair as args.

The **set()** method is part of the **Build** class, the parent class of **Proxy**.

https://thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/9fb8a3b40f24f0c8477776133a2f9cd654ca1c8c/lib/factory_girl/proxy/build.rb

Lines 12-14:

```
def set(attribute, value)
  @instance.send(:"#{attribute}=", value)
end
```

Here @instance refers to the proxied object, the user factory object.

This then, is how **:admin => true** is set as an attribute on the user factory that the railscasts spec code creates.

If you want, you can google "programming design patterns" and read about the following patterns: Factory, Proxy, Builder, Strategy.

Michael Papile wrote:

> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html Notice Array and
>   String etc have similar constructs. I am trying to figure out how they
>   did that now.

If you are still curious, the Array and String you see in the Kernel doc are actually just factory methods used to create new objects of those types.  That's why no **new** method invocation is needed.  They are not actually constructor calls per se, but they do allocate and initialize Array and String objects, and hence under the hood they are doing the equivalent of calling initialize() on objects of those types.  (In C though, of course, not Ruby)

Comment: @favo - Thanks for the edit and enabling the hyperlinks.  Once I realized that creating this first post gave me enough points to re-enable the links I clicked on "edit" and suddenly a green/red diff display popped up showing exactly the edits I wanted to make, with an appopriate edit comment, no less.  As a stackoverflow beginner I at first I thought it was stackoverflow.com's automatically-generated suggestion and I was in complete awe! :)

Comment: your welcome :-) luckily now you can post more links in future answers :-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that second snippet *is* the definition for the function. Function definitions have `def` and `end`. I think that second snippet looks like a function or method being called with an argument of `:user` and a block that takes an `f` parameter.

Of course with metaprogramming you can never really be sure *what* the hell is going on.